# HTML5 Video pause with Javascript when starting to play another video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I was just wondering is there any option to create a Javascript that pauses a video that is currently playing when You click play on another video.
I've got about 30-40 HTML5 video tags on one page.

Code that I'm using to put videos on page:

```
function pobierz_klipy($typ) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Klipy WHERE typ = $typ ORDER BY id")
            or die("Zapytanie niepoprawne");
//ilosc zwroconych wierszy
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $num_rows) {
        $id = mysql_result($result, $i, "id");
        $nazwa = mysql_result($result, $i, "nazwa");
        $nazwa_rob = mysql_result($result, $i, "nazwa_rob");
        $typ = mysql_result($result, $i, "typ");
        $sprawdzian_hq = $sciezka = "../video/data/video/" . $nazwa_rob . "_fb.mp4";

        if (file_exists($sprawdzian_hq)) {
            $sciezka = "../video/data/video/" . $nazwa_rob . "_fb.mp4";
        } else {
            $sciezka = "../video/data/video/" . $nazwa_rob . ".mp4";
        }
        if (file_exists($sprawdzian_hq)) {
            $poster = "../video/data/thumbnails/" . $nazwa_rob . "_fb.mp4.jpg";
        } else {
            $poster = "../video/data/thumbnails/" . $nazwa_rob . ".mp4.jpg";
        }


        if (file_exists($sprawdzian_hq)) {
            $hq = "../video/data/video/" . $nazwa_rob . ".mp4";
        } else {
            $hq = null;
        }
        $i = $i + 1;
        echo "<div class=\"klip\">";
        echo '<video id="' . $nazwa_rob . '" width="320" height="180" controls poster= "' . $poster . '" preload ="none">';
        echo ' <source id="source_' . $nazwa_rob . '" src="' . $sciezka . '" type="video/mp4">';
        echo 'Twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje HTML5.';
        echo '</video>';
        echo '<br />';
        if ($hq != null) {
            echo '<button id="videolink' . $i . '" type="button" class="btn btn-danger active" style=" font-size: 10px; padding: 5px; position: absolute; bottom: 2px; left: 11px;">HQ</button>';
        }
        echo '<div class="nazwa">'.$nazwa.'</div>';
        //skrypt zmiany jakosci JS
        if (file_exists($sprawdzian_hq)) {
            echo '
            <script type = "text/javascript">
                var videobutton = document.getElementById("videolink' . $i . '");

                videobutton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            ';
            echo "
                    var videocontainer$i = document.getElementById('$nazwa_rob');
                    var videosource$i = document.getElementById('source_$nazwa_rob');
                    var newmp4$i = '$hq';
                    var old_mp4$i = '$sciezka';
                    var aktywne$i = 'btn btn-success active';
                    var nieaktywne$i = 'btn btn-danger active';
                    var przycikstatus$i = document.getElementById('videolink$i');
                    var obecny_klip$i = videosource$i.getAttribute('src');
                    var czas_klipu$i = videocontainer$i.currentTime;
                    console.log(czas_klipu$i);

                    if (obecny_klip$i != newmp4$i) {
                        var videosource$i = document.getElementById('source_$nazwa_rob');
                        videocontainer$i.pause();
                        videosource$i.setAttribute('src', newmp4$i);
                        videocontainer$i.load();
                        videocontainer$i.pause();
                        videocontainer$i.currentTime = czas_klipu$i;
                        przycikstatus$i.setAttribute('class', aktywne$i);
                        videocontainer$i.play();

                    } else {
                        var videosource$i = document . getElementById('source_$nazwa_rob');
                        videocontainer$i.pause();
                        videosource$i.setAttribute('src',old_mp4$i);
                        videocontainer$i.load();
                        videocontainer$i.pause();
                        videocontainer$i.currentTime = czas_klipu$i;
                        przycikstatus$i.setAttribute('class', nieaktywne$i);
                        videocontainer$i.play();

                    }


                }, false);

            </script>
            ";
        }
```

Comment: Post some of your code

Comment: Pause all the video elements before playing new video..`videoElement.pause();` and  `videoElement.currentTime = 0;`

Comment: It might be a problem because I use a script that changes quality of video source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use this javascript code.

```js
//external.js
   video = document.getElementsByClassName("video");
        for (i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
            video[i].onplay = function () {
                var currentIndex = index("video", this);
                for (k = 0; k < video.length; k++) {
                    if (k == currenIndex) { continue }
                    video[k].pause();
                }
            }
        }

       
        function index(className, id) {
            nodes = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
            return [].indexOf.call(nodes, id);
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<video class="video" src="video1.mp4" controls></video>
    <video class="video" src="video2.mp4" controls></video>
    <video class="video" src="video3.mp4" controls></video>
    <video class="video" src="video4.mp4" controls></video>
  <script src="external.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With this js implemented any video doesn't even start ;) I mean that it starts to load but it pauses

Comment: It works now :) You forgot "t" at if (k == currenIndex) { continue }  thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Now i've got another issue with this code :

```
<script> video = document.getElementsByClassName("video");
        for (i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
            video[i].onplay = function () {
                var currentIndex = index("video", this);
                for (k = 0; k < video.length; k++) {
                    if (k == currentIndex) { continue }
                    video[k].pause();
                }
            }
}


        function index(className, id) {
            nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("video");
            return [].indexOf.call(nodes, id);
        }
        </script>
```

I've got about 30 video tags on one page. When i try to play 6 videos one after another, the playback of 7th video doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse, i have not been notified. I used them same code to play one after another 30 videos without a problem. try to see if you have not limited the i value to 7 or something like that.
you may have only 7 tags that have 'video' class. if all's right, try to replace. `document.getElementsByClassName` by `document.getElementsByTagName` and try again. sorry not to have responded at time.